# powering Nodemcu using Vin

Tags: esp8266, power, nodemcu

Forgive me for this really dumb question. I am an amateur in electronics, and im trying to wrap up my head around this question and im not able to do so. Need your help.

Im trying to power up a nodemcu using a 5v 1A power supply- I connected +ve to Vin and ground to ground. But i see that 5v is not enough to power up the nodemcu. So i removed the 5V and connected to a 9V battery, and again I find the same issue- the power is not enough. Knowing that i did something wrong - i measured the voltage across Vin and ground and find it to be around 2.5V when using the 5v source and around 2.5V when using the 9 V battery too.

Confused and thinking that my nodemcu is corrupted, i ordered a new one, and did the same. But i find that when i try to supply power using Vin, the voltage across the device- Vin and ground is around 2.5V for the newer device also. Obviously Im missing something.

Can anyone tell me what is it that Im doing wrong. Please tell me how to power a nodemcu without using a usb and only using a 5v source.

Comment: 9V -> Arduino -> VIN -> NodeMCU 5V = dead NodeMCU.

Comment: No. the NodeMCU works on USB power still. Its not dead.

Comment: Then you're lucky that a 9V battery is one of the weakest batteries around, otherwise it would have killed the NodeMCU.  It's the *current* you need to consider. The voltage is 5V and must always be 5V. If it seems "too weak", increasing the *voltage* is a very very bad idea.

Comment: The 5v power supply is 1A. So with that too, the NodeMCU doesnt work. Am I missing something here? Please help me.

Comment: Did you connect the 5v to the Arduino barrel jack or the USB?

Comment: I took a USB charger - 5v 1A and connected its positive to Vin of NodeMCU. I am not using any arduino here.

Comment: Which NodeMCU version?

Comment: second generation.

Comment: What does that mean? NodeMCUs have a version number, not a "generation". What *version number* is printed on your NodeMCU?

Comment: Im sorry. Its V2. I did a google search and found that V2 was called second generation at this blog https://frightanic.com/iot/comparison-of-esp8266-nodemcu-development-boards/.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense - since the earlier boards don't have a VIN pin, they have a 5V pin.

Comment: So... you connected the 5V power supply's positive to VIN. Did you connect the power supply's ground to GND?

Comment: Yeah, i made the connection as you said sir. 5v to Vin and ground to GND.

Comment: why you simple do not google it http://henrysbench.capnfatz.com/henrys-bench/arduino-projects-tips-and-more/powering-the-esp-12e-nodemcu-development-board/

Comment: I referred it long ago. And followed instructions from there only.

Comment: there are different manufacturers

Comment: Yeah sir. However, if i follow the connections as outlined in the blog, i think it must work right? But it doesnt work for me? Is there something that i am missing here?

Comment: fwiw, i have no trouble doing this with CP2102-based nodeMCUs (amica), but I've never gotten it to work with the larger CH340G lolin boards, which also don't give you 5v out when plugged into USB; useless. Your best bet for those is to get a [cheap LDO module](https://www.ebay.com/itm/191847281749) (or smps) and power it from any of the 3.3v pins.

Comment: Im struggling with the same problem, did you finally manage to fix it? Thanks, Pablo

Answer (score 2):

I have a NodeMCU Esp8266 v3 (Lolin) and it works fine conecting Vin and G to my cell phone power supply rated 5.1V, 1000mA. This develop board has a aprotective diode (the closest to Vin), if you have a Multimeter o multitester you can check it measurement continuity. If your diode is damaged the power applied to Vin never be enough to power up the nodemcu.